# Most efficient way to append a constant string to a variable string in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops, concatenation

Currently in my code I have something in a for loop similar to:

```
bstr = bstr + x.charAt(i) + x.charAt(i>>4) + x.charAt(i>>8);
```

Where i is an integer and the loop variable and x is a static final constant string of characters. bstr could be in the order of KBs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A performant way to do this is to use a StringBuilder to concatenate your string:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    builder.append(x.charAt(i));
    builder.append(x.charAt(i>>4));
    builder.append(x.charAt(i>>8));
}

return builder.toString();
```

This technique avoids the problem of storing all the copies of Strings between concatentations across the for loop.

**edit:**

or does this work for you (without adding chars one at a time):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    builder.append(x);
}

return builder.toString();
```

Comment: What do you meane by "all the combinations of concatenations"? An expression such as `a + b + c` is compiled as `new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).append(c).toString()`

Comment: Using `StringBuilder` is a nice way to accomplish this. However, since Java 5, the compiler may automatically convert concatenations into usage of StringBuilder: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/community/kabutz_qa.html

Comment: The JVM does not convert concatenations across a for loop as the question states.

Comment: So, yes the contents of the for loop would be concatenated properly, but across iterations the concatenations would still store each iterative copy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `StringBuilder` before the loop and reuse it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (someCondition) {
    ...
    sb.append(x.charAt(i))
      .append(x.charAt(i >> 4))
      .append(x.charAt(i >> 8));
    ...
}

bstr = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder and just append while you're looping.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(bstr);
for(int i=0; i < somecondition; i++){
  sb.append(x.charAt(i)).append(x.charAt(i>>4)).append(x.charAt(i>>8));  
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `StringBuilder` class. It has an internal array of char, which it appends your contents to until you call the `toString` method, at which point it creates a new `String` object. Of course, since it's using an array to store your characters, it may run out of space, at which point it will copy the contents into a new  larger array. You can avoid that by initially giving it a capacity that will be large enough to hold the final String.

```
// Create a new StringBuilder with an initial capacity that is a little larger than the final String
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(estimatedSizeOfFinalString);
int i = 0;
while (loopConditionIsTrue) {
    builder.append(x.charAt(i)).append(x.charAt(i >> 4)).append(x.charAt(i >> 8);
}
String bstr = builder.toString();
```